# Is this a good way to handle an optional parameter in a stored procedure?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

In a stored procedure, I have an optional parameter, @UserId (uniqueidentifier).  In the SQL that I'm going to use, if the parameter is supplied, then I need to use it in the where clause.  If it isn't, then I should ignore it.  Keep in mind I've got several optional parameters.

To handle this, here is what I've been doing:

```
where (usr.UserId = @UserId OR @UserId is null)
```

Are there some nasty side effects to doing it this way?

This is in MS SQL Server 2014.

Comment: You might want to create the SP [`with recompile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/recompile-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15) so that it generates a new query plan on each invocation. Additional reading: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) and [catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/).

Answer (score 0):

Should be Ok, but if you have a lots of optional parameters then you might want to look into dynamic sql http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-dynamic-sql/

Comment: I have 3 in this specific case.  I just didn't want to get into If @UserId is null then [sql] else [other sql].  Because, with 1 parameter, that is ok.  But adding another doesn't make 1 more if, it makes 3.  And then another, makes, well, like 9 or something.  Using Dynamic SQL is the best option at that point, but I try to stay away from that if at all possible. The possibility for sql injection goes up if we forget QuoteName, and SQL won't as easily create a reusable query plan (this may be old information.)